# numpy - why Y*=2 is faster than Y+=Y?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

## Question

Why `Y*=2` is faster than `Y+=Y`?

```
elepased = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="Y*=2; np.add(X, Y, out=X)",
    setup=setup,
    number=iterations
)
elepased / iterations * 1e6
```

81.25868347997312

```
elepased = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="Y+=Y; np.add(X, Y, out=X)",
    setup=setup,
    number=iterations
)
elepased / iterations * 1e6
```

92.05061321998073

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy as np

X = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.int)
Y = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.int)
"""
iterations = 100000
```

Comment: I've got 3 hypotheses: 1) NumPy might be using a more efficient loop for the array-vs-scalar case (less array iterators, perhaps). 2) NumPy might have an easier time confirming that it doesn't need to copy the inputs to handle input/output overlap in the array-vs-scalar case. 3) Checking for customization hooks like `__array_ufunc__` might go faster in the array-vs-scalar case.

Comment: In my `timeit` tests, `Y+=Y` is modestly faster than `Y*=2`.  But II question whether the time savings over `X+Y+Y` is worth the loss of readability.

Comment: On my computer (2019 Mac Pro) these are the same speed.